# EC2 instance refusing connection to localhost from itself

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to get a Flask app to run on an EC2 instance. I have a few JS functions that send requests to the `localhost` in the backend to retrieve data from an API.

For instance:

```js
if(topicQueryString != null && topicQueryString != ''){
      $.ajax({
          url: 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/search/t/'+topicQueryString,
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) { //do something }
        })
    }
```

However, when deploying the app on my EC2 instance, these requests fail with `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` on `localhost:5000/search/t/topics`

Is there a way to allow the EC2 instance to make requests to itself in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to connect to `0.0.0.0`, not `localhost`. The address `0.0.0.0` doesn't mean `localhost`. You should replace that with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` (which is what localhost means, most of the time).

EDIT: actually, I'm not even sure that I understood the problem correctly. Is that JS code running in a browser? You want that code to connect to a back-end service, presumably not running on localhost? If so, you should use the address of the back-end service, rather than `0.0.0.0` (which doesn't make sense in any context as a destination address to connect to) or `localhost`.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. Firstly, I initially had `localhost` instead of `0.0.0.0`. I tried `0.0.0.0` because when I start my Flask app, I need to use `0.0.0.0` as the host so the outside can reach it. Either way, I got the same error. The JS code is running in a browser, and I want it to connect to a back-end service running on `localhost`. Does that help?

Comment: `localhost` means `the current machine`. If you run the browser in machine A and the back-end code in machine B, then the browser will try to connect to machine A with `127.0.0.1` (or, equivalently, localhost). In other words, it will never try to communicate with machine B. The JS code must point to the machine where the backend is running.

Comment: well this is embarrassing. I don’t know how I forgot such basic information. Quarantine is melting my brain. Thank you for your help!